# issue with angularjs to fetch some data into array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I just join to learn angularjs and i stuck somewhere i was trying to fetch array bunch records from array but it does not work for me can any one take a look and let me know where is my mistake

I have

```
$scope.user = user;

in console i have

Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

0:Object = id:1, name:xzz, lname:xzz;
1:Object = id:2, name:yyz, lname:cdf;
2:Object = id:3, name:sss, lname:dfd;
3:Object = id:4, name:dss, lname:vcd;



angular.forEach($scope.user, function(value, key){
                $scope.sportIds[value.id] = value.id;
                if($scope.sportIds[value.id] == 1){
                  $scope.user = user
                }
            })
```

still it showing up the same result but what i was expecting it shows me like that

```
Array [Object]
0:Object = id:1, name:xzz, lname:xzz;
```

Comment: we need something more. you have that in console for what? the user var? another thing. You have to explain yourself little better

Comment: actually where you want to show the result? can you explain the question clearly

Comment: from service i am getting data in user within array (four objects) in all objects have id i want to match id from object and that should only matchable object in array.

Comment: @aysha 
i want to store the same data in the same variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish but this works with what you are wanting it to return:

```
angular.forEach($scope.user, function(value, key){
  $scope.sportIds[value.id] = value.id;
  if($scope.sportIds[value.id] == 1){
    $scope.user = value;
  }
});
```

This will return the user from `$scope.user` where the `$scope.sportId == 1`. You just had the wrong variable in your function. This can be modified to return a user on different scenarios.

Comment: can i keep alive $scope.user scope value outside of this function

Comment: How will you be using the knowledge of `$scope.user`? I mean can you just set `$scope.validuser = value;` or something like that and then use it for what ever you need it to? This way you can always come back and find the "valid user" from `$scope.user` who has the valid `$scope.sportIds`and act on that.

Comment: Yes ofcourse i can change $scope.validuser also it return objects i want to keep this into array i.e array [object]